# How to access a value inside a value in a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Im having a small concern if we can access a value inside a value.

Eg:
myDict = {1:"Hey", 2:"Bye,1,2,3,4"}

As in the example above..
How can I print/access the value 4 in myDict?? Is it possible with indexing??
Eg: 4  # Printing 4 from myDict

Thanks.

Comment: myDict have 2 pair data: both {1:"Hey"} and {2:"Bye,1,2,3,4"}. Value of myDict[2] is string, you can split by `,` to array. You can get value like that `myDict[2].split(',')[4]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or make a one line loop:

```
value = [i for i in myDict[2].split(',') if i == '4'][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to convert string into array by dividing it by comma ",".

1. Access 2nd element: `result = myDict[1]`
2. Divide it by comma: `result = result.split(",")`
3. Access element: `ans = result[4]`

```
myDict = {1:"Hey", 2:"Bye,1,2,3,4"}
result = myDict[1].split(",")
ans = result[4]
print(ans)
```